# Google Sheets: How to format decimal as fraction in drop down list (data validation)

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, google-sheets-data-validation

I have a cell with data validation. The source of the validation is a long range of decimals  <s>in 0.0078125 (1/128) increments.</s>

The cell containing the validation is formatted to display fractions `# ???/???`

The validation drop down displays decimals `0.000000`

**<s>How do I make the drop down list format the decimals as fractions?</s> 


How do I format the drop down list to display fractions?**

Edit to add clarification images.

Formatted cell displaying fractions:

[image]

Formatted cell and menu not displaying fractions when drop down menu activated:

[image]

I would like to have these displayed as fractions.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display fractions in the dropdown, you need to convert the decimal/formatted value to a text value.

For example:

`=text(A1:A5,"# ???/???")`

If the resulting dropdown value is to be used in a calculation, then you need to convert it back to a number.

For example:

`=left(B10,search("/",B10)-1)/right(B10,len(B10)-search("/",B10))`

---

**SAMPLE**

[image: Dropdown]

---

Comment: That does the trick, thank you!

Comment: I noticed mixed fractions tend to have additional spaces in their formatting: #[space][space]???/???[space] This becomes evident when passing the value to a function and converting to decimal. I stripped out the additional spaces using regex, but do you know why they appear and how to prevent it?

Comment: I'm Learning more each day. To address the extra spacing in my fractions (comment above), I learned that ```# ?/???``` is an acceptable format string and will display the numerator w/o prepending any padding. ```1 1/128``` vs ```1  1/128```.